# Android - How to increase the size of this circle

Tags: android

I've a custom progress circle, this is the code :

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;


public class CustomProgressDialog extends Dialog {
    MaterialProgressBar progress1;

    Context mContext;
    CustomProgressDialog dialog;
    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext=context;
    }
    public CustomProgressDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    public CustomProgressDialog show(CharSequence message) {

        dialog = new CustomProgressDialog (mContext,R.style.ProgressDialog);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_material_progress);

        progress1 = (MaterialProgressBar) dialog.findViewById (R.id.progress1);


        progress1.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.red,R.color.green,R.color.blue,R.color.orange);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        if(dialog!= null) {
            dialog.show ();
        }
        return dialog;
    }
    public CustomProgressDialog dismiss(CharSequence message) {
        if(dialog!=null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        return dialog;

    }


}
```

It makes a circle progress bar like the image below, I want to make it bigger like the double size of the current.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXAly.png)

How can I do so ?

Comment: post your code for `R.layout.view_material_progress`

Comment: I think this link may be helpful to you https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar